# Error trying to Build Xamarin Forms on iOS for Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a solution with Android and iOS projects, running os VS2019 MAC.

The android version builds fine, but the ios I get this error when I try to build:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' (MT2002) (AtendimentoApp.iOS)
```

I've tried to clean the solution, even tried to delete all the bin and obj folders all over the solution but there's no way to build iOS version.

Comment: The Visual Studio is up to date?

Comment: Yes! Everything is up to date! VS for Mac and XCode!

Comment: Please check your references, a situation that should not have "Mono.Android" error during ios compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have `Mono.Android` reference in your iOS project. Remove it and everything will be fine.

Comment: The problem was in the Core project, referencing the Mono.Android for some reason, not in the iOS project.

Comment: So what was the problem exactly Junior Thurler? Should the core project not include Mono.Android?

Answer (score 0):

"Assemblies are resolved recursively; this means that you reference an assembly that references Mono.Android (and there might be even more hops before reaching Mono.Android)"

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22988/error-mt2002-failed-to-resolve-assembly-mono-android-version-0-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickey

This would be of some help.